# Pivot table "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

So what i am doing now is that i have a VBA code that opens up a file and then reformats the excel file, i assigned the code to a button for this code. 
After reformatting the file, i need to create a pivot table based on the excel data that was reformatted.

So i wrote a pivot table code in the module of the excel file that i opened up and ran it. The pivot table was created successfully. However when i copy the codes over to my main file that opens excel files and reformats them, i get an error

> "Invalid procedure call or argument".

I get the error when i try to add a pivot table.

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim pc As PivotCache
 Dim pt As PivotTable

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' set the Pivot-Cache Source Range with the values found for LastRow and LastCol
    Set PRange = Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    If ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Count = 0 Then

        Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=PRange, _
        Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

    Else
        Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches(1)
    End If

 Set ws = Worksheets.Add
 Range("A3").Select

 ' the next line is where the error happens
 Set pt = ws.PivotTables.Add( _
 PivotCache:=pc, _
 Tabledestination:=ActiveCell, _
 TableName:="PIVOTO")

 Set Pf = pt.PivotFields("Driver Name")
 Pf.Orientation = xlRowField

 Set Pf = pt.PivotFields("Over Speeding")
 Pf.Orientation = xlDataField
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the PivotCache and the PivotTable in the same workbook. Something like this.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook

    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    'SourceData:=PRange
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5"), _
            Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)

    '~~> wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") Change to respective range
    Set pt = wb.Sheets(1).PivotTables.Add( _
             PivotCache:=pc, _
             TableDestination:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), _
             TableName:="PIVOTO")
End Sub
```